# C# Pulling query from Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

What I have is a project to convert about 200 or so Crystal Reports to SQL, I know there is no real way to do a 1 for 1 direct correlation, so what I want to be able to do is basically open up each report and dissect it for the query it uses in Crystal Reports, does anybody have an example or a place to start?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm: "SQL" = "SQL Server Reporting Services"?  Or the Crystal Reports use something other than SQL to query a data source currently?

Comment: Not sure, really i'm just trying to extract the query that crystal uses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try RptToXml:

- <del>[Original, VB project](http://code.google.com/p/rpttoxml/)</del>
- [C# replacement](https://github.com/ajryan/RptToXml)

Another alternative is the [PsCrystal](https://github.com/craibuc/PsCrystal) PowerShell module

Comment: Added all updated .NET libraries, installed the run times, the code compiles but fails one of the library calls. spent almost a full day trying to get this to work it just  ** does not work ** : 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
Additional information: Method 'get_HistoryInfos' in type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper' from assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' does not have an implementation. occurred

Comment: @LeoGurdian, see modified answer.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation.  I gave up so I installed crystal reports and opened up the report that way. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You will have to start by looking at the Field Explorer and go piece by piece though that to see where the logic and SQL are located. The SQL itself can be in the the Database Fields pull down but the rest of the sections may have logic that works on those SQL fields for display. I don't know of any shortcuts from there.

Comment: Yeah, I know I could go that route, but I was kinda hoping there was a C# File.readalltext kind of way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine to open up the report and view SQL expressions related to each field.   Check out : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms226185%28v=vs.90%29.aspx